# Ext.ux with extjs open tooling

Tags: npm, extjs

How can one include UX package with the extjs open tooling?

I would like to use ***Ext.ux.ajax.SimManager***

in app.json:

```
    "requires": [
        "font-awesome",
        "ux"
    ],
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@sencha/ext-modern": "~7.0.0",
    "@sencha/ext-modern-theme-material": "~7.0.0",
    "@sencha/ext": "~7.0.0"
  },
```

I've tried to add "@sencha/ext-ux": "~7.0.0" but without success